# what is the best-case / worst-case analysis for the following loop?

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, analysis

no steps are skipped from the outer loop and the second loop which would give us n(n+1)/2 iterations, but i don't know how to compute the innermost loops.

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i =1,j,k;
while(i<=n)
{
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(j%3==0)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=(n/2);k++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }
        else if(j%3==1)
        {
            k=j;
            while(k>=1)
            {
                Console.Write("@");
                k--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(k=1;k<=(j%3);k++)
            {
                Console.Write("$");
            }
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: [You should not be deleting and re-posting the same question just because it has attracted downvotes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039443/worst-case-and-best-case-analysis-big-o)

Comment: Summer classes exist, and its not summer in the southern hemisphere

Comment: Sorry, Rachel. Try editing the question to add some more substance and showing us what you've already tried, with some explanation. You might garner more success that way. Good luck!

Comment: In both cases it is O(n^3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There will be exactly `n` iterations of the first loop.

There will be exactly `n(n+1)/2` iterations of the second loop.

Inside of the second loop there is roughly `1/3` of `n/2` long loops, `1/3` of `j` long loops and `1/3` of `2` long loops.

If we look only at the first of the three possible cases then we get `(n(n+1)/2) * 1/3 * n/2` that is `n*n*(n+1)/12` which is `O(n^3)` or even more precisely `Theta(n^3)`

The two additional cases don't make much difference, they only change constants.

To conclude, in both the pessimistic and optimistic case, this code has to perform a number of iterations that is proportional to `n^3`.

Comment: i don't know why everyone thinks i'm asking my homework in the middle of summer! and simply avoid answering me. i really appreciate your answer it was really helpful, thanks

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -3):

Two tips

- Instead of output inndividual characters, collect them into a string builder and print them once at the end.
- Creating repeating string of a character can be done with the `new string(char, int)` ctor.

Analysis:

- outer-outer loop:linear loop based on n : O(n)
- Outer loop: linear loop based on n : O(n)
- Inner loop: one of either

  - linear loop based on n/2 : O(n)
  - linear loop based on j which is based on i which is based on n : O(n)
  - linear loop based on j which is based on i which is based on n : O(n)
- O(n) * O(n) * O(n) = O(N^3).

You might be thinking that not exactly right -- the first innermost loop is O(n/2), but is Big-O calculations, constants are eliminated, so O(n/2) is the same as O(n).

(UPDATED -- I forgot the outermost loop)

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: `new string(char, int)` is still O(n), not O(1)